# How do I navigate from a document to its parent document set?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-set, modern-experience

There is library of documents sets. Every document set stands for a specific event, has a bunch of metadata attached and groups all event related documents.
There is also a view which shows a flat list of event protocols from all events.

Unfortunately I found no OOTB way to navigate from a protocol file to its parent event document set in SP online modern experience.

I tried to provide a link in a separate column of the protocol list by developing a field customizer. That worked in general but since field customizers are not (yet) supported in the web part view of a list it is of no use for me.

What else can i do?

Answer (score 0):

I think it may depend on the design of your flat view. I have found the following works in flat views that show search results, and in the flat view 'Recent Documents':

Right click on the hyperlink pointing to a doc in the list, and copy the URL. If the doc is in a doc set, the part of the URL up to the last forward slash '/' is the URL of the document set containing the file.

If you paste the URL into the Address field of your browser, delete everything past the last slash and hit enter, it will take you to the document set containing the document.